# How to return text-plain array to a json request in odoo json controller

Tags: python, json, python-requests, odoo

i have to return an array to a json request, but i have a problem

The API need this:

```
[{"pagado":false,"forma_pago":"Procard - Tarjetas de crédito","fecha_pago":null,"monto":"762542.75","fecha_maxima_pago":"2019-02-15 19:30:00","hash_pedido":"247a29c410c278cf1f8ed24db46bf17c3461b96df7cbb5036cbce4fbf20c8e0a","numero_pedido":"194188","cancelado":false,"forma_pago_identificador":"1","token":"f48d99ae8d313142e9fb68260e01dc1c65540544"}]
```

and the API receive this

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":null,"result":"[{'pagado': False, 'forma_pago': 'Procard - Tarjetas de cr\u00e9dito', 'fecha_pago': None, 'monto': '762542.75', 'fecha_maxima_pago': '2019-02-15 19:30:00', 'hash_pedido': '247a29c410c278cf1f8ed24db46bf17c3461b96df7cbb5036cbce4fbf20c8e0a', 'numero_pedido': '194188', 'cancelado': False, 'forma_pago_identificador': '1', 'token': 'f48d99ae8d313142e9fb68260e01dc1c65540544'}]"}
```

I need to return just the array, and I don hnow whatś my problem, here is the code of my controller

```
import json


@http.route('/pagopar/confirmacion_pago/', auth='public', methods=['POST'], type='json', csrf=False)
def index(self, **post):
    data1 = request.httprequest.data
    my_json = data1.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
    data_dict = json.loads(my_json)
    a = 0
    if data_dict['respuesta']:

        if True:                
            arr_return = []
            arr_return.append(data_dict['resultado'][0])
            return {'response': arr_return[0]}
```

before the return I print the arr_return[0] to my log and I got good results, but the API not

Thanks!
 And sorry for my bad English